# Apple Store Macbook Pro DVI and VGA Adapter questions - what is in the box?

Tags: macbook-pro

The company I work for recently ordered me a Macbook Pro and I received the shipping confirmation today. Among the machine configuration there is listed the following:

- DVI Adapter 065-0106 None
- VGA Adapter 065-0108 None

What do these lines mean? Does it mean that these adapters are not part of the configuration? If not is there still a way for me to hook up an external monitor that has a DVI or VGA input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video out on MacBook Pro uses a Displayport / Thunderbolt port. To hook up to a VGA or DVI cable, you need an adapter. Alternatively you could buy a cable which has Displayport on one end and DVI or VGA on the other. The adapters don't come as standard so you'll need to buy one in an Apple store, online or use a third-party cable.

Answer (score 1):

Apple always put these lines to confirm they are or are not in the package, don't worry. You will be able to connect to every monitor or projector on the planet with the right adaptor. :-)

Comment: Yeah I was a little confused as to why they listed it and then said 'None'!